# Reset css class, remove .selected

Tags: jquery, css

I have few element that have class .selected, I want to reset them. If I do `$('.selected').remove()`, it will remove the element instead of the class. What to do?

Comment: Use [`removeClass('selected')`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Comment: Show your code first.

Comment: google before posting question.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('.selected').removeClass('selected')
```

Comment: Don't add answer as `try this`. Add some explanation

Answer (score 1):

To remove class use [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

> Description: Remove a single class, multiple classes, or all classes from each element in the set of matched elements.

Like this

```
$('elementIDorClass').removeClass('ClassName')
```

Sample

```
$('.selected').removeClass('selected')
```

Answer (score 1):

`.remove()` function removed elements itself, jQuery does provide function to remove element's class. That is `removeClass()`, try this :

```
// provide class name without `.`
$('.selected').removeClass('selected')
```

You might need read this Doc to differentiate each other :

1. [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)
2. [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)